# PHP FTP connecting but not reading folder

Tags: php, ftp

I have a code I am trying to connect to a different server via PHP FTP connection.
I know that I am actually connecting to the server.

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

var_dump($login);
```

when I `vardump` the `$login`, I get a `TRUE`.

When I try to upload a file I get a *'error uploading file'*
so I tried to just pull a list of files on the connection:

```
$file_list = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, ".");
var_dump($file_list);
```

It's only returning `bool(false)`.
I know the connections has files because  I can view them via FileZilla with the same credentials.

Any idea what might be wrong? Is it possible a server setting that isn't allowing me to use this PHP script from a shared server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most typical cause of problems with `ftp_list` (`ftp_nlist`, `ftp_put` and other functions that require separate FTP data connection) is that PHP defaults to the active mode. And in 99% cases, one has to switch to the passive mode, to make the directory listing and transfer working. Use the [`ftp_pasv` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php).

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass) or die("Login failed");
// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true) or die("Unable switch to passive mode");
```

See *my* article on the [active and passive FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

Comment: True life saver ! Thank you.